# How to create AppStore.com short link?

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes, app-store-connect

For my resume, I am attempting to add a shortened link to the app that I created. I looked around and found that apple provides a link shortener for iOS apps using the AppStore.com URL.

Unfortunately, since my app contains the ² character, I cannot figure out how to link to my app.

The long link for my app is:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/squared2/id498133871?mt=8

Also, is there a way to link to an app without having iTunes automatically open (only show the iTunes preview page)?

Comment: Useful workaround for the second question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944489/creating-an-app-store-short-link/20006367#20006367 Find the app on the store from an iOS device. Share it via a message. Copy the link from there.

Answer (score 8):

According to the rules explained in the [Technical Q&A QA1633](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1633/_index.html), here it is

```
http://appstore.com/squared²
```

You have to:

- Remove all whitespace
- Convert all characters to lower-case
- Remove all copyright (©), trademark (™) and registered mark (®) symbols
- Replace ampersands ("&") with "and"
- Remove most punctuation, namely `` !¡"#$%'()*+,\-./:;<=>¿?@[\]^_`{|}~ ``
- Replace accented and other "decorated" characters (ü, å, etc.) with their elemental character (u, a, etc.)
- Leave all other characters as-is.

That said, `appstore.com` links, also know as *canonical App Store Short Links*, automatically redirect to iTunes when open in a browswer.

Comment: I don't believe that link shows the preview page but instead redirects you to open the link in itunes.

Comment: True, I added a note. That is the link the OP is looking for, but it doesn't do they want.

Comment: The only problem with them is I don't get previews (like in facebook)... so I'll use itunes links for now..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a url shortener service like [bit.ly](http://bit.ly). Also usually the web browser will prompt you on how you want to proceed with the url. For Chrome it asks me if I want to continue viewing the preview web page or open it in iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

All AppStore.com short links, such as `http://appstore.com/squared²`, will automatically open iTunes. There's no way to stop iTunes URLs opening iTunes (if it's installed) for all users.

Comment: Did you try it? It opened iTunes and displayed @acidic's app for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can have a short link.

`https://itunes.apple.com/app/id<Apple ID>`

Ex: `https://itunes.apple.com/app/id375380948`

Answer (score -2):

This link you have works fine.  Can you expand on the problem?

Also, the name of app is meaningless in the url.  This link works just as well:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/meaningless/id498133871?mt=8

Comment: I am trying to find the link to my app that starts with www.AppStore.com/(myapp)