# How do I get a URL for my app before submitting it?

Tags: ios, url, app-store, itunes

In my app you can post a message to facebook or twitter, I want to include a link to my app in these posts by default, I've setup & tested the function in the app which works fine but I'd like to know how I get a URL for my app in the app store before submitting it? I've registered the app with iTunes Connect which gives a 'View in App Store' link, when I click this it provides a URL but only for the US, my app is most likely to be used in the UK so I'd need a UK URL.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459416/how-to-create-appstore-com-short-link?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your link will also work in other countries. iTunes knows to search for the app in your current store. However, if you want the browser to open the UK store (before iTunes itself is launched) you can change the URL part that says:

https://itunes.apple.com/us...

to:

https://itunes.apple.com/gb...

Comment: I didn't think it'd be that simple! Plus I wasn't sure if the URL generated when I registered the app in iTunes connect was a temporary/for testing URL or if it would/could change after approval! Thanks